# how to open and application from system tray?

Tags: java, swing, system-tray

how to send java application in system tray by close button and restore by click on system tray icon?.

i have try follow to hide but now how i can get back it by click on system tray?

```
 getFrmTaskList().setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
```

how it is possible can any one give me proper suggestion have already tried all other way by searching in search box

Comment: if JFrame is defined as local variable, e.g. myFrame.setVisible(true) for myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);

Comment: yes i have done this but now how i can show it by click on to the system tray?

Comment: follows code example from official Oracle tutorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    This is example code you can create appropriate listener and make it working
    //Check the SystemTray is supported
    if (!SystemTray.isSupported()) {
        System.out.println("SystemTray is not supported");
        return;
    }
    final PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu();
    final TrayIcon trayIcon =
            new TrayIcon(createImage("images/bulb.gif", "tray icon"));
    final SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();

    // Create a pop-up menu components
    MenuItem aboutItem = new MenuItem("About");
    CheckboxMenuItem cb1 = new CheckboxMenuItem("Set auto size");
    CheckboxMenuItem cb2 = new CheckboxMenuItem("Set tooltip");
    Menu displayMenu = new Menu("Display");
    MenuItem errorItem = new MenuItem("Error");
    MenuItem warningItem = new MenuItem("Warning");
    MenuItem infoItem = new MenuItem("Info");
    MenuItem noneItem = new MenuItem("None");
    MenuItem exitItem = new MenuItem("Exit");

    //Add components to pop-up menu
    popup.add(aboutItem);
    popup.addSeparator();
    popup.add(cb1);
    popup.add(cb2);
    popup.addSeparator();
    popup.add(displayMenu);
    displayMenu.add(errorItem);
    displayMenu.add(warningItem);
    displayMenu.add(infoItem);
    displayMenu.add(noneItem);
    popup.add(exitItem);

    trayIcon.setPopupMenu(popup);

    try {
        tray.add(trayIcon);
    } catch (AWTException e) {
        System.out.println("TrayIcon could not be added.");
    }
```

Comment: how this can send my application in system tray and how can open application by click on the system tray icon?